# Disable printing JAVA_OPTS on console of JBoss server

Tags: logging, jboss

I have configured keystore details in standalone.xml file of jboss server.

While starting the server it is printing all the details about keystore on console and server.log file.

How to disable printing of this details on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually hibernate is printing these details.
[org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
at INFO level of log.

So I have configured hibernate log level to ERROR level.

```
<logger category="org.hibernate">
      <level name="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

in standalone.xml